# What is the typical vertical angle field of view for a PIR motion sensing light switch?

Tags: motion-sensor

PIR (passive infrared) motion sensing light switches advertise the arc for which they detect motion, but that is only the horizontal arc. I can't find information on the vertical angle for their field of view. This can be important for a bathroom frequented by small children. Is there a typical angle they all have, or is there somewhere this is specified?

I have an one I'm testing right now that has a very narrow vertical arc, so I'm wondering if they're all like that or just this specific product.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm sure they differ, but if you can't find the info in their specs then you'll have to test each one you're considering.

Comment: Are you sticking to PIR sensors here, or would a *dual technology* (PIR/ultrasonic) sensor be an option?

Comment: Since the question is about the angle, let's consider PIR only. But it's good to know ultrasonic might behave differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### While it varies by the sensor, we can look at a good representative unit to get an idea

You are right that different sensors will be somewhat different with regard to their view angles, both in the horizontal and vertical planes.  A good sensor should provide numbers, or better yet, a diagram that specifies their viewing area in both axes though; this should either be given in a specification sheet/document, or provided by some sort of applications literature.  (There is a specification in NEMA WD-7 that governs this, and commercial-grade sensors such as a Lutron Maestro or a Legrand Wattstopper will comply with it, but there's no telling when it comes to random stuff on big-box shelves...)

For example, the diagram below, reproduced from page 59 of the [Lutron Occupancy/Vacancy Sensor Design and Application Guide](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/3683197.pdf), provides an application-level specification for both horizontal and vertical sensor coverage for the Maestro PIR sensors at a given sensor installation height, provided the sensor has an unobstructed line of sight to the motion source.

[image: Lutron Maestro coverage diagrams]

Comment: Thank you. That helps a great deal, especially noticing that the view angle is not symmetrical vertically. It sees more down than up.